Implementing custom lasso regression with fixed features in sklearn pipeline for variable selection
There are two posts related to this topic in R language including fixed regressor in a Lasso regression model and fixed effect Lasso logit model
I am writing a feature selection model using Lasso penalisation, my data has some seasonal dummy variables and they must not be dropped during the modelling phase. The easiest way to do so is the shrinkage applied to the coefficients on the linear model should avoid the coefficients of fixed features. Could you please help me write a custom Lasso function which does not shrink the coefficients of fixed features and is callable in sklearn Pipeline?**
 from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
 pipeline = Pipeline([
           ('scaler', StandardScaler()),  # Optional: Feature scaling
           ('lasso', LassoWithFixedFeatures(fixed_features_indices))
     ])


I have tried this,
from sklearn.base import BaseEstimator, RegressorMixin
from sklearn.linear_model import Lasso
import numpy as np

class LassoWithFixedFeatures(BaseEstimator, RegressorMixin):
    def __init__(self, fixed_features_indices, alpha=1.0):
        self.fixed_features_indices = fixed_features_indices
        self.alpha = alpha

    def fit(self, X, y):
        # Fit Lasso model with regularized coefficients
        self.lasso = Lasso(alpha=self.alpha)
        self.lasso.fit(X, y)

        # Calculate the penalty term for fixed features
        penalty_fixed = self.alpha * np.abs(self.lasso.coef_[self.fixed_features_indices])

        # Set coefficients of fixed features to their original values
        fixed_features_coefs = np.linalg.lstsq(X[:, self.fixed_features_indices], y, rcond=None)[0]
        self.coef_ = np.zeros(X.shape[1])
        self.coef_[self.fixed_features_indices] = fixed_features_coefs

        # Calculate the penalty term for non-fixed features
        penalty_non_fixed = np.zeros(X.shape[1])
        penalty_non_fixed[self.fixed_features_indices] = 0  # Exclude fixed features from penalty
        penalty_non_fixed[~np.isin(np.arange(X.shape[1]), self.fixed_features_indices)] = self.alpha * np.abs(self.lasso.coef_)

        # Update coefficients by considering penalties
        self.coef_ += self.lasso.coef_ - penalty_non_fixed + penalty_fixed

        return self

    def predict(self, X): 
        return np.dot(X, self.coef_)

There were total 18 regressors and 7, I have kept at fixed_features. I was expecting lasso regression with custom shrinkage but got
ValueError: 
All the 500 fits failed.
It is very likely that your model is misconfigured.
You can try to debug the error by setting error_score='raise'

Below are more details about the failures:
500 fits failed with the following error: Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:\Users\...py", line 732, in _fit_and_score
    estimator.fit(X_train, y_train, **fit_params)   File "C:\..\base.py", line 1151, in wrapper
    return fit_method(estimator, *args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   File "C:\Users\...py", line 420, in fit
    self._final_estimator.fit(Xt, y, **fit_params_last_step)   File "C:\Users\...5759.py", line 26, in fit
    penalty_non_fixed[~np.isin(np.arange(X.shape[1]), self.fixed_features_indices)] = self.alpha * np.abs(self.lasso.coef_)
    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ ValueError: NumPy boolean array indexing assignment cannot assign 18 input values to the 11 output values where the mask is true


I've fixed the indexing problems, but can't comment on the correctness of the coefficient calculations - consider posting it on stats.stackexchange.com. I've just tried to make the program flow clearer:
        # Final coefficients by considering penalties
        self.coef_ = (
            #Lasso coefs are the starting point for all of the features
            self.lasso_.coef_
            
            #Fixed features: add lstsq coefs and penalties.
            #  They become: lasso coef + lstsq coef + nonneg penalty
            + original_coef_fixed
            + penalties_fixed
            
            #Remaining features: subtract penalty.
            #  They become: lasso coef - nonneg penalty
            - penalties_nonfixed
        )

Data for testing:
from sklearn.datasets import make_regression
import pandas as pd

X, y = make_regression(n_samples=500, n_features=17, n_informative=17)
X_df = pd.DataFrame({
    feat: vals for feat, vals in zip([f'feat{i}' for i in range(17)], X.T)
})
fixed_features_indices = np.arange(7)

from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline

lasso_ff = LassoWithFixedFeatures(fixed_features_indices)
pipeline = Pipeline([
        ('scaler', StandardScaler()),  # Optional: Feature scaling
        ('lasso', lasso_ff)
])

pipeline.fit(X, y).predict(X)
pipeline.fit(X_df, y).predict(X_df)

Modified class:
from sklearn.base import BaseEstimator, RegressorMixin
from sklearn.linear_model import Lasso
import numpy as np

from sklearn.base import check_X_y, check_array, check_is_fitted

class LassoWithFixedFeatures(RegressorMixin, BaseEstimator):
    def __init__(self, fixed_features_indices, alpha=1.0):
        self.fixed_features_indices = fixed_features_indices
        self.alpha = alpha

    def fit(self, X, y):
        #Check and convert to numpy
        X, y = check_X_y(X, y)
        
        #Define the various groups of indices
        feature_indices = np.arange(X.shape[1])
        nonfixed_features_indices = feature_indices[
            ~np.isin(feature_indices, self.fixed_features_indices)
        ]
        
        # Fit Lasso model with regularized coefficients
        self.lasso_ = Lasso(alpha=self.alpha).fit(X, y)
        abs_lasso_coefs = np.abs(self.lasso_.coef_)
        
        #Initialise penalty vectors relevant to different indices
        # and calculate penalties
        penalties_fixed = np.zeros_like(feature_indices)
        penalties_nonfixed = np.zeros_like(feature_indices)
        
        penalties_fixed[self.fixed_features_indices] = (
            self.alpha * abs_lasso_coefs[self.fixed_features_indices]
        )
        
        penalties_nonfixed[nonfixed_features_indices] = (
            self.alpha * abs_lasso_coefs[nonfixed_features_indices]
        )

        # Original values of the coefficients for the fixed features
        original_coef_fixed = np.zeros_like(feature_indices)
        original_coef_fixed[self.fixed_features_indices] = np.linalg.lstsq(
            X[:, self.fixed_features_indices], y, rcond=None
        )[0]
        
        # Final coefficients by considering penalties
        self.coef_ = (
            #Lasso coefs are the starting point for all of the features
            self.lasso_.coef_
            
            #Fixed features: add lstsq coefs and penalties.
            #  They become: lasso coef + lstsq coef + nonneg penalty
            + original_coef_fixed
            + penalties_fixed
            
            #Remaining features: subtract penalty.
            #  They become: lasso coef - nonneg penalty
            - penalties_nonfixed
        )

        return self

    def predict(self, X):
        check_is_fitted(self)
        X = check_array(X)
        return X @ self.coef_.reshape(-1, 1)

